# how to pass value from textbox to another page textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys I hope you well.

Any one who can help I have a problem here I want to pass value from textbox to another page textbox using javascript.

Here is my curfrent code.

**Page one**

```
<form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        Name:
        <input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" value="Mudassar Khan" /><br />
        <br />
        Technology:
        <select id="ddlTechnolgy" name="Technology">
            <option value="ASP.Net">ASP.Net</option>
            <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
            <option value="JSP">JSP</option>
        </select>
    <input type="button" id="btnQueryString" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnQueryString").bind("click", function () {
                var url = "pagetwo.html?name=" + encodeURIComponent($("#txtName").val()) + "&technology=" + encodeURIComponent($("#ddlTechnolgy").val());
                window.location.href = url;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Page two**

```
<form id="form1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var queryString = new Array();
        $(function () {
            if (queryString.length == 0) {
                if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                    var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                        var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                        var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                        queryString[key] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (queryString["name"] != null && queryString["technology"] != null) {
                var name = queryString["name"];
                var technology = queryString["technology"];
                $("#fname").html(name);
                $("#tech").html(technology);
            }
        });
    </script>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/>
      <input type="text" id="tech" name="tech"/>
    </form>
```

Please help me.